# Yii Crop Image upload using Ajax Issue

Tags: php, jquery, yii, yii-extensions

Hi I am just trying to upload image using navajcrop in yii extension. which upload image using ajax call. I am able to upload image. but problem is that uploaded image can not be view.when i view uploaded image it display below error:- Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x75 0xab)

controller code:-

```
public function actionUpload(){
    $model = new Register();
    if(isset($_POST)){
        $rnd = rand(0, 9999);
       $img = $_POST['image']; 

        if($img != '/img/noimage.png' && $img != $model->image){  
            $img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);


            $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
           $data = base64_decode($img); 

            $file = Yii::app()->basePath . '/../themes/front/assets/img/photo/' . $rnd.'.jpg'; 

                       file_put_contents($file, $data);

        }
    }
}
```

JS code :-

```
function doSomething(obj,res){ //the 'obj' is IMG tag, 'res' is base64image

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'post',
        //url: <?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('site/upload');?>,
        url: baseUrl+"/admin/ajax/Upload",
        data: 'image='+res,
        success: function(){ 
            obj.attr('src',res);
        }
    });
}
```

view code:-

```
<?php            $this->widget('ext.NavaJcrop.ImageJcrop', array(
    'config' => array(
        'title'=>$model->image,
        'image'=>$model->image,//required, all field below are not required.
        'id'=>'nava-jcrop',
        //'unique'=>true,
        'buttons'=>array(
            'cancel'=>array(
                'name'=>'Cancel',
                'class'=>'button-crop',
                'style'=>'margin-left: 5px;',
            ),
            /*'edit'=>array(
                'name'=>'Edit',
                'class'=>'button-crop',
                'style'=>'margin-left: 5px;',
            ),*/
            'crop'=>array(
                'name'=>'Crop',
                'class'=>'button-crop',
                'style'=>'margin-left: 5px;',
            )
        ),
        'options'=>array(
            'imageWidth'=>150,
            'imageHeight'=>175,
            'resultStyle'=>'position: fixed;top: 400px;max-width:350px;max-height:350px;z-index: 9999;',
            'resultMaxWidth'=>350,
            'resultMinWidth'=>350,
        ),
        'callBack'=> array(
            'success'=>"function(obj,res){doSomething(obj,res);}",
            'error'=>"function(){alert('error');}",
        )

    )
));  ?>
```

Please help to solve this erro.

Comment: hi amit , you are saying that you are able to load image, but have you tried to directly open that file ? it seems no to have appropiate extension...

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have solved my question it was bug in below syntax.

in controller action :- edit

$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);

$file = Yii::app()->basePath . '/../themes/front/assets/img/photo/' . $rnd.'.png';